# excel not responding after closing Find menu that is opened with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a button in a excel sheet that opens the Find menu (ctrl+f).

```
Sub Button6_Click()

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaFind).Show

End Sub
```

After the search is done and one closes this menu excel doesn't respond anymore and closes itself. Any ideas why?

Also, I don't get the exact same find dialog as when I use ctrl+f. Is there maybe a way to use keyboard-functions in vba?

Why not use ctrl+f instead of the button. Because my colleagues are not quite good with excel and that already is too much to remember for them :)

Comment: It is ideal for me, works completely fine. Replaced this line with 'Application.SendKeys ("^f")'

Comment: Ah read your question then saw that you actually asked for it, deleted my comment and put an answer in just as you replied haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how to mimic a key press in VBA `^` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**

```
Sub Button6_Click()

Application.SendKeys ("^f")

End Sub
```